# MultiLabelling to recognize subclasses for multi object detection in images

Tags: tensorflow, classification, yolo, multilabel-classification, faster-rcnn

I'd would like to classify objects (dices in particular) with a method based on YOLO, or Faster RCNN. I'm using my own database, and I would like to label my images in order to pass it to my model. However, I was thinking of using LabelImg to do so, but I can't find any way to label classes and subclasses (i.e first get the type of dice, and then the designated face).

Is there a simpler way to do that, than labelling my images twice (for type and face), and pass it to two different models ?

Thank you guys, any suggestion is welcome !

Comment: Would also be interested in this answer